# What is the best way to get an elements opposite index in an array?

Tags: algorithm

Say I have array

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

- index 0 and 4 are opposites
- index 1 and 3 are opposites
- index 2's opposite is undefined

Or

```
 {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

- index 0 and 5 are opposites
- index 1 and 4 are opposites
- index 2 and 3 are opposites

I remember seeing a really clever way to do this. Something like

```
i%array.length
```

Comment: umm... what is the pattern? How are the pair items related?

Comment: no pattern, just the opposite index

Comment: The first one's pattern makes sense (except 3 would be its own "opposite"). The second one makes no sense to me. Why the pairs (1, 5), (2, 4), and (3, 6)?

Comment: what counts as opposite? I would imagine as `1` being opposite to `6` , `2` to `5` and `3` to `4` in the six-element case.

Comment: umm... the elements you show as paired are not at the positions you indicate. Please recheck your second example.

Comment: i meant index. i thought it was self-explanatory but there should be no room for confusion now.

Comment: Pattern of first is `index -> (length - 1) - index`. Pattern of second does not follow.

Comment: I have updated the example numbers so they now match the index they have.

Comment: A better way to phrase the question is: "How do I find the element in a forward-indexed array corresponding to a given reverse index?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
oppIndex = array.length - firstIndex - 1;
```

Comment: @user1873073 - From the question "index 2's opposite is undefined" I guess OP really didn't want undefined if the result was the same number

Answer (score 1):

```
array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
idx = 0 /* 0 is the first array position with value of 1 */

IF array.length - idx - 1 > idx
   RETURN array[ array.length - idx - 1 ] /* returns array[4] == 5 */
ELSE
   RETURN undefined

array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
idx = 2 /* 2 is the third array position with value of 3 */

IF array.length - idx - 1 > idx /* 5 - 2 - 1 == 2 which is NOT greater than 2 */
   RETURN array[ array.length - idx - 1 ]
ELSE
   RETURN undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Following what your first example logic ...

```
       if (array.length%2==0){
            for (int i =0; i<array.length/2; i++){
                   syso("the opposite of "+ array[i] + " is " + array[array.length -1-i]
             }
       }
       else {
           for (int i =0; i<floor(array.length/2); i++){
                   syso("the opposite of "+ array[i] + " is " + array[array.length -1-i]
             }
             i = i+1
              syso("the opposite of "+ array[i] +" is undefined"
       }
```

Comment: I think you're off by one. Also, I think you only wanted to print each pair once, not twice.

Comment: this is good but i thought i saw it done in just one line somewhere.

Comment: should be better now isn't it ? (not really beautifull though)